# Touch screen changing

Tags: touchscreen, android-versions

Can we replace the touchscreen of 5.5-inch size, 720p resolution in a smartphone to the same size but with 1080p resolution touchscreen? Is there any possibility? Or is it not possible? If not why?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible *theoretically*, but impractical because of some reasons.

1. Android needs drivers to communicate with the hardware, and because you are replacing a hardware part, the old drivers will refuse to communicate with the new screen in a lot of cases, and you'll probably have to delete these drivers from the kernel source, rewrite these drivers (likely thousands of lines of C code) compile it and flash your new kernel.
2. The vendor of your device could have modified the way the screen interact with the motherboard. So unless if you are lucky to come upon a higher resolution screen that uses exactly the connection schemes of the old screen, you won't be able to replace it.
3. Your other hardware are probably not powerful enough to drive the higher resolution.

If you can overcome these difficulties, congratulations, you could replace your touchscreen! :)